# How can I add CommandBar buttons in SharePoint online using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, modern-experience

[image]

As shown in figure I want to add button on each CommandBar in SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about you can do it via C# Client OM, but if you are familiar with `SharePoint Framework` you can use its `Extensions` part create add buttons to command bar.

SPFx Extensions has three part `ApplicationCustomizers` for customizing header and footers, `FieldCustomizers` for defining rendering of field (similar to CSR, in classic SP) and finally `CommandSets` to add custom actions to command bar as well as contextual menu.

Your must explore the `CommandSets` in [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api).